# iOS Swift 4 Status bar - disable Translucent

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

I am trying to get the status bar of my iOS (webView) app not Translucent.

I tried this inside func viewDidLoad():

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

And this in the appDelegate:

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .white
```

This is what I am getting when scrolling the page..
[image]

Comment: Do you have a navigationBar? Cannot really see from you screenshot

Comment: Depends, your view is anchored to superview and not a safeArea which is better. This will fix it. But you might want different type of behaviour.

Comment: check your constraints. scrollView TopConstraint must be anchored to SafeArea not to superView

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot change those properties for the status bar. You can only set, .default, .lightContent. But if you want you can probably place a view underneath of it, which is not translucent and has a background color. Something like this:

```
let statusBarFrame = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame
let statusBarView = UIView(frame: statusBarFrame)
self.view.addSubview(statusBarView)
statusBarView.backgroundColor = .green
```

That can go in you `viewDidLoad()` method of the `ViewController`

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 5.1 iOS 13.0 Just in case for the current deprecations...**

```
 if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {

            let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
            let statusBarFrame = window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame

            let statusBarView = UIView(frame: statusBarFrame!)
            self.view.addSubview(statusBarView)
            statusBarView.backgroundColor = .green
        } else {
            //Below iOS13
            let statusBarFrame = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame
            let statusBarView = UIView(frame: statusBarFrame)
            self.view.addSubview(statusBarView)
            statusBarView.backgroundColor = .green
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me when trying to slide a view from above into the screen, without seeing it on status bar while it animates:

```
view.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can play with status bar translucency. However, you might want to hide it. Paste the following code in your ViewController:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
  return true
}
```

If it doesn't work, check in your `Info.plist` if your status bar appearance is ViewController based. Add this:

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<true/>
```